# MS Access = referencing a control that is within a sub form

Tags: ms-access, forms, vba, subform

So I have a form, with a subform control that acts as a navigation scheme for my Main Form. Within the sub form, there is a sub form2 that actually contains the controls for data entry.

So the Main Form is almost just like a design shell around the sub2 within sub1 structure. So in subform1 there is 10 clickable buttons that open 10 different forms in the subform2 window. The subform2 contains the controls.....so here is my issue/question:

So if I have a click event on the subform2 where i am trying to open the next form (subform2 form) within the subform1 child control, which is within the Main Form, what is the vb syntax for handling this?

I am not sure if i am asking this correctly.

I tried:

```
Forms!SubForm1.MyChild.sourceobject = "NextSubForm2"
```

but this only works if the Main Form is not open....like if I only had the SubForm1 open.

One more thing, this is code behind the form of the SubForm2 (2 being the sub within the sub within the form).

Comment: So this is from the Main form's level/perspective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main form from a subform's point of view is:

```
Me.Parent
```

You can build on this:

```
Me.Parent.Subform1ControlName.Form.AControl
```

See also: http://www.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

So:

```
Me.Parent.Subform1ControlName.SourceObject = "SomeForm"
```

Comment: @Remou....I understand what you are saying about the main form from the subform point of veiw...but what about a sub form within a subform within a main form?  sorry I know this is getting all "Inception"...lol. Would 'Me.Parent' just reference one level up, or skip to the main form, or not even work?

Comment: @Remou....neverming...the link is very helpful...I was missing the lower section of it. Thanks guys!